# Stub a React hook using cypress

Tags: reactjs, mocking, cypress

I'm trying to get my head around the way that `cypress` does things and I come from mostly a PHP background so I'm a bit confused.

I have a very simple React component

```js
import React from 'react';
import LoginButton from '../atom/LoginButton';
import LogoutButton from '../atom/LogoutButton';
import { useAuth0 } from '@auth0/auth0-react';

const AuthenticationButton = () => {
  const { isAuthenticated } = useAuth0();

  return isAuthenticated ? <LogoutButton /> : <LoginButton />;
};

export default AuthenticationButton;
```

and I am trying to write a test to ensure that the login/logout button appears

```
import {mount} from '@cypress/react18'
import AuthenticationButton from './AuthenticationButton'
import { useAuth0 } from '@auth0/auth0-react';

it('should display login if not authenticated', () => {
    mount(<AuthenticationButton/>)
    cy.get('button').contains('Log in');
});

it('should display logout if authenticated', () => {
    cy.stub(useAuth0, 'isAuthenticated').returns(true);
    mount(<AuthenticationButton/>);
    cy.get('button').contains('Log out');
});
```

I currently get the error `Cannot stub non-existent own property isAuthenticated`. I think because `isAuthenticated` is a property and not a function. Is there a way I can mock the property to be `true`?

Comment: Generally speaking, you'd "mock" a property by setting it's value to something you specifically want it to be. But that property is the return value a React hook, which runs in the background process of React itself, so when you mount or re-render it's going to reset the value. Don't you want to stub the hook itself to control what it gives to the component?

Comment: @SuchAnIgnorantThingToDo-UKR that sounds like it could be a plan. Do you have any more info on how to stub the hook or do you need anything more from me?

Comment: I was thinking about this [react-hooks-testing-library](https://react-hooks-testing-library.com/), but not sure how to use it with Cypress.

Comment: Just to update this as I have had time to do a bit more research, there seems to be a github issue related to it - https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/14672#issuecomment-1279068760

Comment: Have you ever gotten it to work? I see the issue has been resolved for hook testing, but your test was never about hook testing, but for component rendering.

Comment: Honestly @RobinG I really can't remember it was far too long ago and I have moved away from the project. I think I changed cypress version and followed the advice on the useHook migration (https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/migration-guide#React-mountHook-Removed) Sorry I can't be more help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm no longer working on the project so can't even test an answer if it was provided. If anyone finds this and wants an answer I would look into the changes that they made in Cypress with the removal of `useHook` - https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/migration-guide#React-mountHook-Removed

I will be closing the issue :) Thanks to all who contributed